# Is it a good idea to duplicate columns across tables in order to enforce check constraints?

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

I'm faced with a situation where I have two tables: A and B.  B has a foreign key to A.

A has a column "Detailed" which identifies whether or not its children in B require their "Details" section to be filled out.

If I have my lean structure there is no way for me to determine if a record in B needs to have its "Details" section filled out, i.e. not null, without joining to A.  Thus, the only way for me to prevent somebody from inserting or updating these records to an invalid state is to have a trigger to join with A and check its "Detailed" column.

My feeling is that constraints are better than triggers, as they are more like facts about data, in addition to filters, whereas triggers are only filters.

I could get by this by duplicating the "Detailed" column in B and then having a check constraint (Detailed = 'Y' AND Details IS NOT NULL) OR (Detailed = 'N')

Thoughts on the best way to approach this?

Comment: if you duplicate the column into table B, what will keep it in sync with table A? leave it in A and use a trigger.

Comment: If I were to go that route I would enforce synchronicity in the foreign key from B to A.

Comment: with a FK between the two, it would then be impossible to change the value of "Detailed".

Comment: @KM: in Oracle, data constrained by foreign key relationships can still be updated, by deferring the constraint checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the tools you mentioned (constraints and triggers) are just a way to enforce the data consistency in the database.

Simple business rules, like "always having a reference", "not having a `NULL`" etc are enforceable with the constraints.

More complex business rules, like the one you mention here, should be enforced using triggers.

Constraints are not "better" or "worse" than triggers: they are just a shortcut for the rules you need to implement often.

For your task, just implement a trigger.

However, in `Oracle`, both constraints and triggers are implemented not in pure set-based way. They are called in a loop for each record affected by a `DML` operation.

Most efficient way would be creating a package that would serve as a single entry point to all `DML` against your table and check the `Details` in that package.

Comment: Good suggestions... I've already been using a package for all DML operations but as I'm not an expert in PL/SQL yet I felt most comfortable adding these constraints as a backup in the event that my understanding of the locking mechanisms and isolation levels are not airtight.  Apart from Oracle's guides and google searches, any suggestions for resources on mastering these topics?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're right to enforce this on the database level and Quassnoi's points are all good.  In addition, you might want to investigate having the API for this operation reference an [updatable join view](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/views.htm#i1006232) of the two tables and implement the constraint through that.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world, Oracle and other DBMSs would support "assertions":

```
create assertion no_more_than_50_per_user as
check(not exists(select null
                 from a join b on ...
                 where a.detailed = 'Y'
                 and b.details is null
);
```

They don't though (and not without good reason: it would be very hard to implement them in a performance manner!)

As Quassnoi suggests, triggers can be used instead - but you need to be aware of the dangers in a multi-user environment.  To be sure of enforcing consistency you need to take out locks when checking data to ensure that this doesn't happen:

(Assume A record 1 currently has detailed='N', but all associated B records have details not null).

```
user1> Update A set detailed = 'Y' where a_id=1;
```

That works, because all the associated B rows have details not null.

```
user2> Update B set details = null where a_id=1;
```

That works, because user1 hasn't committed yet, so user2's trigger sees detailed='N'.

```
user1> commit;
user2> commit;
```

Now you have corrupt data.  To prevent that, the trigger on B needs to select the A row "for update".

Answer (score 0):

I would enforce a rule like this in the UI. If your business rules become more complicated, you are going to have your hands full with lots of redundant columns in your model in order to enforce all rules in the database schema.

Comment: then an application bug, a different rogue application, manual data update, or a bad script makes a change can break the data.

Comment: I'm currently enforcing these rules in several places (client, server, database) but as the application I'm using has many concurrent users potentially affecting the same data, I'm trying to eliminate the possibility of two simultaneous requests passing the app layer checks and then changing these records to invalid states.  I think I'll need to lock database records in order to achieve this level of safety rather than adding extra columns.

Comment: As long as performance is not a problem, enforcing this in the database is fine, and will give you peace of mind that your data won't get corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If the DETAILED field was to be duplicated on B you could use the foreign key to enforce it, e.g. (B.KEYFIELD, B.DETAILED) REFERENCES (A.KEYFIELD, A.DETAILED).  I'm not crazy about duplicating the field on B, but on the other hand it seems that you have data which is related to B which exists on A.  If you could remove DETAILED from A and push it down to B the design might be cleaner.  Some additional details might help.

Share and enjoy.